# Jaydata ServiceOperation and Action method POST ignored

Tags: odata, jaydata

I work on the Jaydata release 1.3.6 (with OData V3) and i have a problem with Service Operations and Actions, they are all submitted wia the GET method instead of POST...

I have to change GET to POST because of my $filter request which is to big for a GET request (limit string length).

I've tried many possibilities like :

```js
$data.EntityContext.extend('Default.Container', {
    'Items': { type: $data.EntitySet, elementType: Entities.Item, method: 'POST' },
    'GetItemsAction': { type: $data.ServiceAction, returnType: $data.Queryable, elementType: 'Entities.Item', 'EntitySet': 'Item', params: [] },
    'GetItemsOperation': { type: $data.ServiceOperation, returnType: $data.Queryable, elementType: 'Entities.Item', 'EntitySet': 'Item', params: [], method: 'POST' }
});
```

The Service Action is meant to have the method action to POST by default, but it's always in GET, even if I manually set the method for a ServiceOperation the method parameter is ignored...

I've set a .Net OData Controller with my methods in POST:

```cs
[EnableQuery]
public IQueryable<Item> Get(ODataQueryOptions<Item> options)
{
    return this._itemRepository.GetAll();
}

[HttpPost]
[EnableQuery]
public IQueryable<Item> GetItemsAction(ODataQueryOptions<Item> options)
{
    return this._itemRepository.GetAll();
}

[HttpPost]
[EnableQuery]
public IQueryable<Item> GetItemsOperation(ODataQueryOptions<Item> options)
{
    return this._itemRepository.GetAll();
}
```

Is there a problem with the implementation of Jaydata?

Thanks for your advices !